# remote desktop from windows 10 to ubuntu 22.04

Tags: server, password, remote-desktop, vnc, remote

i am new to linux but is time to learn
i have installed ubuntu 22.04 and i need to use this as server for nextcloud but i like to be able to connect with remote desktop to this computer
i have enabled the remote desktop on ubuntu and i have succesfuly connected from my windows 10 laptop with tightvnc viewer
i have then find out that the password changes every time i rebood the device so after litle search i have found a way to stop change the password by login automaticaly on ubunte and remove the password from "password and keys" utility
now the problem is that i want to have the ubuntu pc without monitor and this is not working
when no monitor is connected i can't connect with tightvnc viewer

is there any easy solution for beginers to remote desktop from windows to ubuntu?

i have tried the windows rdp but asks me to enter my credentials and is not clear what password it asks
i have try everything i know but nothing works

please help
thank you

Comment: If you will be setting up the machine as a NextCloud server, wouldn't it make more sense to simply `ssh` into it? Setting up NextCloud happens from the command line anyway, so why install a the desktop environment - also in terms of security. Or will this be a home server that isn't exposed over the internet?

Comment: Yes i guess is more safe without the desktop environment but i like to add more stuff to this server and because i am not that good on linux command line i feel better to have graphical interface

Comment: Ok i am installing now from the beginning this time ubuntu server and i will try ssh